# DatePicker not Available for telerik GridDateTimeColumn

Tags: datepicker, telerik, telerik-grid

I created a telerik:GridDateTimeColumn using the markup below. However, the date in the grid is not editable. Am I missing something?

```
<telerik:GridDateTimeColumn 
                                         DataField="VerificationDate" 
                                         HeaderText="Verification Date"
                                         UniqueName="VerificationDate" 
                                         PickerType="DatePicker"
                                         DataFormatString="{0:M/d/yyyy}"
                                         ItemStyle-Wrap="false" 
                                         ItemStyle-Width="200px" 
                                         HeaderStyle-Width="200px" />
```

Comment: In editmode you are not able to see datepicker in the grid, right?

Comment: It wasn't in edit mode. I'm somewhat new to using Telerik Grids. I wanted it to load in edit mode with in-place edit. I think I might use templates

Comment: GridDateTimeColumn in non-edit mode is simply displayed as text. When you switch to edit mode it will display a date picker. Please see the telerik demo: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/columns-rows/columns/column-types/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: I wanted the datepicker to be in edit mode at all times.